# Android Application doesn't start Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider

Hey, I'm trying to implement a service on my Android Application. And the Service must do the same task of the Activity. IE, if some change happen on the CallLog.Calls content provider the service must be notified and insert the data in the database even if the application is not running, I mean, a service will be running after the application is started, so if the application is killed, the service will keep running until the OS stop it, right?

So it will be running on background collecting all data that changes on the CallLog.Calls service. But, the service is not running. I star it in onCreate() method of the Activity. And inside the Service I implemented a ContentObserver class that uses the method onChange() in case somethind changes in the CallLog.Calls content provider.

What I don't know is why the Service is not started, and why it doesn't work even if I kill the app on the DDMS perspective.

Here is the code.

The Activity called **RatedCalls.java**

```
public class RatedCalls extends ListActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "RATEDCALLSOBSERVER";
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private CallDataHelper cdh;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(RatedCalls.this);
private Integer contentProviderLastSize;
private Integer contentProviderCurrentSize;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    cdh = new CallDataHelper(this);
    db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    startService(new Intent(this, RatedCallsService.class));
    registerContentObservers();

    Log.i("FILLLIST", "calling from onCreate()");

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");

    contentProviderLastSize = cursor.getCount();

}

class RatedCallsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public RatedCallsContentObserver(Handler h) {
        super(h);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RatedCallsContentObserver.onChange( " + selfChange
                + ")");
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        searchInsert();

    }
}

private void searchInsert() {

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");

    Log.i("FILLLIST", "Calling from searchInsert");

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    int numberColumnId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int durationId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int contactNameId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int numTypeId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE);

    Date dt = new Date();
    int hours = dt.getHours();
    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
    String currTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();

    cursor.moveToFirst();           

            String contactNumber = cursor.getString(numberColumnId);
            String contactName = cursor.getString(contactNameId);
            String duration = cursor.getString(durationId);
            String numType = cursor.getString(numTypeId);
            stopManagingCursor(cursor);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("contact_id", 1);
            values.put("contact_name", contactName);
            values.put("number_type", numType);
            values.put("contact_number", contactNumber);
            values.put("duration", duration);
            values.put("date", dateFormat.format(date));
            values.put("current_time", currTime);
            values.put("cont", 1);

            db.insert(CallDataHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);         
}
    public void registerContentObservers() {

    this.getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .registerContentObserver(
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, true,
                    new RatedCallsContentObserver(handler));

}
```

And this is the Service called **RatedCallsService.java**

```
public class RatedCallsService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "RatedCallsService";
private static final String LOG_TAG = "RatedCallsService";
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private CallDataHelper cdh;
OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(RatedCallsService.this);

class RatedCallsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public RatedCallsContentObserver(Handler h) {
        super(h);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RatedCallsContentObserver.onChange( " + selfChange
                + ")");
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        searchInsert();

    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Rated Calls Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    registerContentObservers();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Rated Calls Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    cdh = new CallDataHelper(this);
    db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Rated Calls Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");      
    registerContentObservers();

}

private void searchInsert() {

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");

    Log.i("FILLLIST", "Calling from searchInsert");

    int numberColumnId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int durationId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int contactNameId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int numTypeId = cursor
            .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE);

    Date dt = new Date();
    int hours = dt.getHours();
    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
    String currTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String contactNumber = cursor.getString(numberColumnId);
            String contactName = cursor.getString(contactNameId);
            String duration = cursor.getString(durationId);
            String numType = cursor.getString(numTypeId);           
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("contact_id", 1);
            values.put("contact_name", contactName);
            values.put("number_type", numType);
            values.put("contact_number", contactNumber);
            values.put("duration", duration);
            values.put("date", dateFormat.format(date));
            values.put("current_time", currTime);
            values.put("cont", 1);

            db.insert(CallDataHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }
}


public void registerContentObservers() {

    this.getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .registerContentObserver(
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, true,
                    new RatedCallsContentObserver(handler));

}

 }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just see if you have added this Service in your manifest file.......

Thanks.......

Answer (score 5):

When declaring the service in your manifest, try using the full package location of your service class in your manifest.

eg. `<service android:name="com.company.project.package.MyService">`

My service wasn't starting and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [service lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) documentation.  If you call Context.startService() the service should start and stay running until someone tells it to stop.

From your code sample, it looks like you are doing that.  What makes you think that the service isn't starting?

I'm not sure what you expect to happen when you kill the app... That sounds like a good reason for it not to work.

Answer (score 1):

Hi instead of using a service and a content observer i would observe the phone state. Observing the phone state can trigger your update service.

You need the

> android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

permission. which isn't a big affair.

The code for the broadcast receiver is

```
    public class CallStateWatcher extends BroadcastReceiver
{



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED))
        {
            String extra = intent.getStringExtra(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if (extra.equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
            {
                // do something
            }
            if (extra.equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
            {
                // do something

            }   

        }
    }
}
```

You have to define that receiver

```
<receiver
        android:name=".core.watcher.CallStateWatcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```